# exrm fails due to unreachable_package

Tags: release, elixir, elixir-mix, exrm

First time trying out exrm. Build failing because unreachable_package. Can't seem to find what package is the issue. Any insight into where I should be looking would be much appreciated.

```
===> Provider successfully run: app_discover
===> Running provider resolve_release
===> Solving Release telnet_client-0.0.1
===> Provider (resolve_release) failed with: {error,
                                                 {rlx_prv_release,
                                                  {failed_solve,
                                                   {unreachable_package,
                                                    telnet_client}}}}
==> Failed to build release. Please fix any errors and try again.
```

Comment: Details, details, details!  Which version of EXRM?  Which version of Elixir?  Which version of Erlang?  Which OS?  I know you answered your question yourself below but if anyone else runs into a similar issue I'm sure they'd like to know if the details are the same or not.

Comment: Seems related to this: https://github.com/bitwalker/exrm/issues/269

Answer (score 0):

Removing the build_path and config_path seems to have done the trick.

```
 build_path: "../../_build",
 config_path: "../../config/config.exs",
```

Comment: Seems like it is trying to use telnet, but it's failing to either get/download a dependency or using a telnet client it expects to be available in the system. Are you on Windows? 

Are those paths you removed from your project or from exrm?